# CakePHP 3 beforesave access modified entity data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to access the submitted data inside the beforeSave method in my table class but all I get is the data saved in the database.

```
public function beforeSave($event,$entity,$options)
{
    // submitted data is ABC
    // the value DEF is currently in the database
    debug($entity->get('tag_string')); // DEF
    debug($entity->tag_string); // DEF
    debug($entity['tag_string']); // DEF
    debug($entity); // the tag_string property is ABC (submitted value)
    if($entity->tag_string)
    {
        $entity->tags=$this->buildTags($entity->tag_string);
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I access the submitted data inside the beforeFilter method?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: how can I access the submitted data inside the beforeFilter method?

**If** you mean by "submitted data" the request data, you can't. It has been converted into an entity by the marshaller at this point.

And before you re-invent the wheel for tags, try this plugin https://github.com/UseMuffin/Tags

Comment: the question is about the beforeSave method. I don't really know how it's suposed to work but I'm certain that inside the Table::beforeSave() method you can access the submitted data.

Comment: The cookbook doesn't say much about accessing data but you can see submitted data in the $_POST variable but that's not a conventional cake way

Comment: I well aware that he tries to access the data there. Which is wrong in the context of the architecture. He needs to change his approach but since he is not giving any more info...